# Weird .gitignore

Tags: git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Django test app to Heroku and I'm doing all the Git things. The problem is when I create the `gitignore`. 
I create the `gitignore` with the code:

```
echo > .gitignore
```

Then the console asks for the files and I enter the env folder and other things (the Python GitHub recommendation), but the folders and files aren't ignored.

So I used GitKraken to ignore and unfollow that files and by my surprise works! But the software adds these characters at the end of the document:

```
਍湥⽶਍
```

I'm using VS Code, Python 3.6.2, Django 2.0.3. 
I don't understand what is happening with those characters, help!

Comment: What asks for the files? Not `echo > .gitignore`, surely?

Comment: `InputObject[0]:`
then i put `env/`

Comment: Oh, is this PowerShell? Try just editing the `.gitignore` with your text editor.

Comment: You can use the `touch` command to create blank files.

Answer (score 0):

Your file has something messed up with encoding, try editing & fixing it in simple text editor like notepad on windows or leafpad on linux